# Is there a way to stream Azure Information Protection Activity Logs to an Event Hub?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-information-protection

I have configured Azure Information Protection analytics through the Azure portal for my subscription and I am able to see log data under the Activity logs (preview) tab.

[image]

I want to forward that log data to a configured Event Hub but I have not found a way to do it.  This data appears to be written to a table called InformationProtection_CL.  How do I get that query output to stream to an Event Hub?  Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the REST API [`Query - Get`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/query/get) to get the log data in the table.

```
GET https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/{workspaceId}/query?query={query}
```

Then follow this doc to send events to the event hub programmatically, the specific situation and language depend on you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send#send-events

Comment: This solution allowed me to bypass event hubs altogether.  Even better!